# How do i read numbers into an outfile in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

How do I get numbers from an infile to be used on an outfile?

for example, say i want to read numbers in an infile and use those numbers to display as student ids on an outfile.

Comment: If this is homework, please mark it as so.

Comment: this is basically related to the other question he just asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652295/how-do-i-do-this-c-program

Comment: @Robert this kind of input i called formatted input.

Comment: Do you mean you want to read numbers from a file (stream) and write the numbers to another file (stream)?

Comment: @Martin - I *think* he's trying to write numbers to a data file and then (later) read thm back.

Comment: A quick Google for C++ tutorial: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how you wrote the values.

Obviously you need to open the file.
If you wote the data with `outfile << data`, you will probably read it with `infile >> data`.

If you used `fprintf()`, you will probably read it with `fscanf()`, though not necessarily.

To start off, how about you show us what you did to write the outfile, and mave a quick try at how you might read it and show us that.  Then we can give you some guidence on how to proceed.

Good Luck!

**Update**
You seem fairly lost.  I've written a short program that does some of the things you need, but I haven't included any comments so you need to read the code.  Have a look and see if you can figure out what you need.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


bool WriteNums(const std::string &sFileName, int nVal, double dVal)
{
    std::ofstream ofstr(sFileName);
    if (!ofstr.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Open output file failed\n";
        return false;
    }
    ofstr << nVal << " " << dVal;
    if (ofstr.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "Write to file failed\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool ReadNums(const std::string &sFileName, int &nVal, double &dVal)
{
    std::ifstream ifstr(sFileName);
    if (!ifstr.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Open input file failed\n";
        return false;
    }
    ifstr >> nVal >> dVal;
    if (ifstr.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "Read from file failed\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string sFileName("MyStyff.txt");
    if(WriteNums(sFileName, 42, 1.23456))
    {
        int nVal(0);
        double dVal(0.0);

        if (ReadNums(sFileName, nVal, dVal))
        {
            std::cout << "I read back " << nVal << " and " << dVal << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: outfile.open("Robert_pay.out"); is how i opened my file i am going to try the infile >> data.

Comment: so am i supposed to get the integers one at a time like the infile.get, or is ther another method?

Comment: it won't read all the numbers it keeps starting me in the middle of the file

Comment: @Robert I have added some sample code above.  If my "write" code is very different from yours, then the "read" code may not work, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`istream_iterator` and `ostream_iterator` are pretty fun.

Check out the neat things you can do with it. Here's a simple example of a Fahrenheit to Celsius converter that reads the input and makes output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
typedef float input_type;
static const input_type factor = 5.0f / 9.0f;

struct f_to_c : public unary_function<input_type, input_type>
{
    input_type operator()(const input_type x) const
    { return (x - 32) * factor; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// F to C
    transform(
        istream_iterator<input_type>(cin),
        istream_iterator<input_type>(),
        ostream_iterator<input_type>(cout, "\n"),
        f_to_c()
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty cool program, but I'm not certain that a beginner (like Robert) will get much from it.

Comment: @Michael: Well if he understands it then he'll be a long ways towards writing C++ and not C with classes.